# How to use autocomplete inside a dialog box using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have a form inside of a dialog box that is displayed when a user click on a button. When a user starts tying inside a field I want to display available options found inside a database.

The available options will need to be read using an AJAX request.

Here is my jQuery code where I try to initialize the `autocomplete()`

```
$("#icwsTransferTo")
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {

        $.ajax({    
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'index.php',       
            data: {method: 'userSearch', term: request.term},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
                if(!data){
                    return;
                }


                var array = $.map(data, function(m) {
                return {
                        label: '<div syle="display: block;"><span>' + m.configurationId.displayName + '</span><span style="float: right"> (' + m.extension + ')</span></div>'
                    };
                });
                response(array);

            }
        }); 

    },
    search: function() {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {

        alert('Worked!');

    }
});
```

The field `icwsTransferTo` is located inside of a form which is displayed in the dialog box.

The problem is that when typing 2+ characters, I see the spinning icon in the field but no results is ever presented.

When I do a manual call to the `index.php?method=userSearch&term=mike` I get results like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [configurationId] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => msmith
                            [displayName] => Mike Smith
                            [uri] => /configuration/users/msmith
                        )

                    [extension] => 2062
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [configurationId] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => mjohns
                            [displayName] => Mike Jones
                            [uri] => /configuration/users/mjohns
                        )

                    [extension] => 2083
                )
        )
)
```

what am I doing wrong here? Why the results are not showing?

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? I am assuming you are using the Jquery UI autocomplete? According to their documentation here: [Documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) you should pass it a JSON array not html

Comment: @ChrisMitchell the `array` is an array of  elements `{label: "..."}`, not HTML.

Comment: @ChrisMitchell I converted my array to `JSON` string which worked. If you post your comment in an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the Jquery UI autocomplete? According to their documentation here: [Documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) you should pass it a JSON array not html.